# GWT (Client) = How to convert Object to JSON and send to Server?

Tags: java, gwt

I know that GWT has a good RPC support. But for various purposes I need to build this on my own:

1.) How can I convert a Bean Object (on the Client Side) like;

```
class MyPerson {

String name;
String getName();
void setName(String name);
//..    
}
```

with GWT into a JSON String? (Ideally only using libraries that come officially from GWT/Google).

2.) Secondly, how can I send this generated JSON String from the Client side to any Server also using any GWT Client Logik. (Ideally only using libraries that come officially from GWT/Google).

I have searched a lot, but the examples never show how to send data but only to receive JSON data.

Thank you very much!!!
Jens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a nifty class called AutoBeanFactory that GWT will create for you, no third-party libs required.  See http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9219/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/editor/client/AutoBeanFactory.html

Once you have your AutoBeanFactory, you can use it like this:

producing JSON from an object of type SimpleInterface

```
AutoBean<SimpleInterface> bean = beanFactory.create(SimpleInterface.class, simpleInterfaceInstance);
String requestData = AutoBeanCodex.encode(bean).getPayload();

useRequestBuilderToSendRequestWhereverYouWant(requestData);
```

parsing JSON from an object of type SimpleInterface

```
SimpleInterface simpleInterfaceInstance = AutoBeanCodex.decode(beanFactory, SimpleInterface.class, responseText).as();
```

You can use `RequestBuilder` to send these requests without GWT-RPC or the RF stuff.

Comment: and dont forget to inherit the module: `<inherits name="com.google.web.bindery.autobean.AutoBean"/>`

Comment: How do you get an instance of `beanFactory`?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you use [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html) it makes JSON rest services work just like GWT RPC services.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GWT's [AutoBean](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) framework, which can be used to create and receive JSON payloads.  The [`RequestBuilder`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) type can be used to send HTTP requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have also another solution which is 3rd party solution, maybe a second place solution but it can be also the first place. 
The 3rd party called GSON and it's a project open source on google code. 
You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

I used it and it's very good and very simple.

Comment: GSON cannot be used on GWT client side because it uses reflection.