# how to convert JSON to Java object and vice versa in GWT project?

Tags: json, rest, gwt

I am using a GWT for client side application and REST web service instead of server(not using RPC or servlets in GWT). I want to convert java object to JSON and pass JSON object from client to server and also server to client. But for processing I want to convert JSON object to java object i server. GSON is not supporting by GWT is there any way to convert java object to JSON object and vice versa?

I did a sample project using Autobean framework for converting java object to JSON , but I got the following error

```
[ERROR] [gwtmodules] - Deferred binding result type 'com.mycompany.gwtmodules.client.MyFactory' should not be abstract
] Failed to create an instance of 'com.mycompany.gwtmodules.client.Gwtmodules' via deferred binding 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mycompany.gwtmodules.client.MyFactory' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
```

Following is my code

```
public interface Test {


    public int getAge();
    public void setAge(int age);
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);

}

import com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBean;
import com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanFactory;

public interface MyFactory extends AutoBeanFactory{
AutoBean<Test> test();
}
public class Gwtmodules implements EntryPoint {

    MyFactory factory = GWT.create(MyFactory.class);

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    Test makeTest() {
        // Construct the AutoBean
        AutoBean<Test> test = factory.test();

        // Return the Person interface shim
        return test.as();
    }

    Test deserializeFromJson(String json) {
        AutoBean<Test> bean = AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory, Test.class, json);
        return bean.as();
    }

    String serializeToJson(Test test) {
        // Retrieve the AutoBean controller
        AutoBean<Test> bean = AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(test);
        return AutoBeanCodex.encode(bean).getPayload();
    }

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        final Test test = makeTest();
        test.setAge(44);
        test.setName("achu");
        final Button button = new Button("Click here");
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                String s = serializeToJson(test);
                Window.alert("alert" + s);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658936/gwt-client-how-to-convert-object-to-json-and-send-to-server

Comment: I think the answer to this post can be helpful for this issue too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683123/json-java-serialization-that-works-with-gwt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**is there any way to convert java object to JSON object and vice versa?**

You can use autobean framework of GWT. It can be used at server and client both side.

- [AutoBean framework](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#GWT_AutoBean_framework)

**Example:**

```
String serializeToJson(Test test) 
{
    // Retrieve the AutoBean controller
    AutoBean<Test> bean = AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(test);
    return AutoBeanCodex.encode(bean).getPayload();
}

Test deserializeFromJson(String json) 
{     
    AutoBean<Test> bean = AutoBeanCodex.decode(myFactory, Test.class, json);     
    return bean.as();   
}
```

Comment: Which module i need to inherit it for this?

Comment: I got this error " No source code is available for type com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBean<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module? "

Comment: In your project.gwt.xml : <inherits name="com.google.web.bindery.autobean.AutoBean"/> to fix this issue.

Comment: [ERROR] [gwtmodules] - Deferred binding result type 'com.mycompany.gwtmodules.client.MyFactory' should not be abstract

Comment: import com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBean;
import com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanFactory;

public interface MyFactory extends AutoBeanFactory{
AutoBean<Test> test();
}

Comment: what is a package structure of MyFactory interface? It should be inside of source path. i.e. <source path='client'/> in gwt.xml file.

Comment: Can you solve the following error?                                                                                                                                  Deferred binding result type 'com.mycompany.gwtmodules.client.MyFactory' should not be abstract

Comment: The code does not have any problem. Try to debug your code. do you use any gin framework? It is issue with something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419724/deferred-binding-failed

Comment: I did so, but no use same error. I did all code in client side is it a problem? It always showing the following error Deferred binding result type 'com.mycompany.gwtmodules.client.MyFactory' should not be abstract

Comment: Now this is my error " [ERROR] [jsonconvertapp] - Line 71: No source code is available for type com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter; did you forget to inherit a required module?"

Comment: The comments which you added it is showing you solving one by one problem and in progress. Ask new question for second problem and accept this answer. if you ask a question like this others might not attention on it. and others can not help you.